# PNG Tiles for Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have png tiles structured in folders (generated by Mapnik and Maperitive). What is the best way to use these tiles in Geoserver to create wms? I need this base layer from tiles with second one layer of route and provide it to client. When I try load it with ImagePyramid plugin, I've got error about 404000 projection:

```
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: No transformation available from system "EngineeringCRS[Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit]" to "GeographicCRS[WGS84(DD)]".
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box way to expose those tiles, you'll have to write some java code in the GeoWebCache project